# Diffeomorphism between a sphere and ellipsoid in $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Diffeomorphism between a sphere and ellipsoid in $\mathbb R^3$.

I've been looking for an diffeomorphism between a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ and an ellipsoid of the form $$\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid \frac {x^2} {a^2} + \frac {y^2} {b^2} + \frac {z^2} {c^2} = 1\}$$

I know from linear algebra such an ellipsoid can be represented as a matrix product $x^T A x = 1$, but how can this be used to get a diffeomorphism ?

Can such a diffeomorphism be found for a general ellipsoid ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denote by $E$ your ellipsoid, and by $S^2$ the sphere $\{x \in \mathbf R^3 \mid x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1\}$. Define a map $f \colon E \to S^2$ by 
$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{x_1}a, \frac{x_2}b, \frac{x_3}c \right) $$
Then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: can a diffeomorphism be given from any sphere

Comment: If $S = \{x \in \mathbf R^3 \mid \|x-x_0\| = r\}$ is any sphere, note that $g \colon S^2 \to S$, $x \mapsto r(x+x_0)$ is a diffeomorphism between $S$ and $S^2$. Compose if with $f$.

Comment: How do you compute the inverse of $f$ ?

Comment: $f^{-1}(x) = (ax_1, bx_2, cx_3)$?!